# How to implement node.js and RFID?

Tags: node.js, localhost, rfid

Does anyone know how do I go about implementing this?
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adF-H9mLuFs&feature=youtu.be

It will be great if anyone can provide me with step by step implementation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The RFID reader must have some kind of documentation for how you can use it.

There is probably a smarter way that you can link it to nodejs but one method would be to have the rfid reader write the data to a csv file and have nodejs watch that file via fs.watch. ([See **fs.watch** in docs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener))

You would fire an event that reads the file each time it is written and then do whatever you like. You can update the browser using websockets. (See http://socket.io/)

Comment: This is probably not a great way to do it but it would work. Hope it helps!